# Display unique value from the output

Tags: powershell

i have script which display drivers information from the host. But i am looking for unique values output no duplicate Name-Device.

Condition:-
Incase if the Name-Device is similar but Version are different. I want to keep both Name-Device and Version information too.

```
Name-Device                               Device-Class                              Module                                    Version                                 
-----------                               ------------                              ------                                    -------                                 
Cisco VIC Ethernet NIC                    Ethernet controller                       enic                                      Version 2.3.0.16, Build: 2494789, Int...
Cisco VIC Ethernet NIC                    Ethernet controller                       enic                                      Version 2.3.0.14, Build: 2494585, Int...
```

code:-

```
$host.system.module.get($hosthard.ModuleName) |
Select @{N='Name-Device';E={$hosthard.DeviceName}},@{N='Device-Class';E={$hosthard.DeviceClassName}},Module,Version | unique -OnType
```

output:-

```
Name-Device                               Device-Class                              Module                                    Version                                 
-----------                               ------------                              ------                                    -------                                 
Lewisburg SATA AHCI Controller            SATA controller                           ahci                                      Version 3.0-26vmw, Build: 5050593, In...
Lewisburg USB 3.0 xHCI Controller         USB controller                            xhci                                      Version 1.0, Build: 4600944, Interfac...
Lewisburg PCI Express Root Port #1        PCI bridge                                vmkernel                                  Version Releasebuild-5050593            
Lewisburg PCI Express Root Port #5        PCI bridge                                vmkernel                                  Version Releasebuild-5050593            
x1 PCIe Gen2 Bridge[Pilot4]               PCI bridge                                vmkernel                                  Version Releasebuild-5050593            
Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port 1A       PCI bridge                                vmkernel                                  Version Releasebuild-5050593            
VIC 1300 PCIe Upstream Port               PCI bridge                                vmkernel                                  Version Releasebuild-5050593            
VIC PCIe Downstream Port                  PCI bridge                                vmkernel                                  Version Releasebuild-5050593            
VIC PCIe Upstream Port                    PCI bridge                                vmkernel                                  Version Releasebuild-5050593            
VIC PCIe Downstream Port                  PCI bridge                                vmkernel                                  Version Releasebuild-5050593            
Cisco VIC Ethernet NIC                    Ethernet controller                       enic                                      Version 2.3.0.14, Build: 2494585, Int...
Cisco VIC Ethernet NIC                    Ethernet controller                       enic                                      Version 2.3.0.14, Build: 2494585, Int...
Cisco VIC Ethernet NIC                    Ethernet controller                       enic                                      Version 2.3.0.14, Build: 2494585, Int...
Cisco VIC Ethernet NIC                    Ethernet controller                       enic                                      Version 2.3.0.14, Build: 2494585, Int...
Cisco VIC Ethernet NIC                    Ethernet controller                       enic                                      Version 2.3.0.14, Build: 2494585, Int...
Cisco VIC FCoE HBA Driver                 Fibre Channel                             fnic                                      Version 1.6.0.34, Build: 2494585, Int...
Cisco VIC FCoE HBA Driver                 Fibre Channel                             fnic                                      Version 1.6.0.34, Build: 2494585, Int...
Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port 1C       PCI bridge                                vmkernel                                  Version Releasebuild-5050593            
Cisco 12G Modular Raid Controller with... RAID bus controller                       lsi_mr3                                   7.701.14.00-1OEM.600.0.0.2768847        
Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port 1C       PCI bridge                                vmkernel                                  Version Releasebuild-5050593            
Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port 1D       PCI bridge                                vmkernel                                  Version Releasebuild-5050593
```

I am looking for output like below:-I mean unique values not duplicate.

```
        Name-Device                               Device-Class                              Module                                    Version                                 
-----------                               ------------                              ------                                    -------                                 
Lewisburg SATA AHCI Controller            SATA controller                           ahci                                      Version 3.0-26vmw, Build: 5050593, In...
Lewisburg USB 3.0 xHCI Controller         USB controller                            xhci                                      Version 1.0, Build: 4600944, Interfac...
Lewisburg PCI Express Root Port #1        PCI bridge                                vmkernel                                  Version Releasebuild-5050593            
x1 PCIe Gen2 Bridge[Pilot4]               PCI bridge                                vmkernel                                  Version Releasebuild-5050593            
Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port 1A       PCI bridge                                vmkernel                                  Version Releasebuild-5050593            
VIC 1300 PCIe Upstream Port               PCI bridge                                vmkernel                                  Version Releasebuild-5050593            
VIC PCIe Downstream Port                  PCI bridge                                vmkernel                                  Version Releasebuild-5050593            
VIC PCIe Upstream Port                    PCI bridge                                vmkernel                                  Version Releasebuild-5050593            
Cisco VIC Ethernet NIC                    Ethernet controller                       enic                                      Version 2.3.0.14, Build: 2494585, Int...
Cisco VIC FCoE HBA Driver                 Fibre Channel                             fnic                                      Version 1.6.0.34, Build: 2494585, Int...
Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port 1C       PCI bridge                                vmkernel                                  Version Releasebuild-5050593            
Cisco 12G Modular Raid Controller with... RAID bus controller                       lsi_mr3                                   7.701.14.00-1OEM.600.0.0.2768847        
Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port 1C       PCI bridge                                vmkernel                                  Version Releasebuild-5050593
```

Comment: What is your question?  Have you tried anything to achieve the desired result?  What constitutes values where, as you say, "Name-Device is similar"?  It would be helpful if you'd show specific examples of what should and should not be considered duplicates instead of leaving it to the reader to compare your two (very much in need of [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)) output listings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could strip off trailing hex values and #-sign  from `Name-Device`

on the fly with a `Sort-Object`  and the `-Unique` parameter

```
| Sort-Object {($_.'Name-Device' -split ' [\d#a-f]{2,}$')[0]},Version -Unique
```

That would return:

```
Name-Device                               Device-Class        Module   Version
-----------                               ------------        ------   -------
Cisco 12G Modular Raid Controller with... RAID bus controller lsi_mr3  7.701.14.00-1OEM.600.0.0.2768847
Cisco VIC Ethernet NIC                    Ethernet controller enic     Version 2.3.0.14, Build: 2494585, Int...
Cisco VIC FCoE HBA Driver                 Fibre Channel       fnic     Version 1.6.0.34, Build: 2494585, Int...
Lewisburg PCI Express Root Port #1        PCI bridge          vmkernel Version Releasebuild-5050593
Lewisburg SATA AHCI Controller            SATA controller     ahci     Version 3.0-26vmw, Build: 5050593, In...
Lewisburg USB 3.0 xHCI Controller         USB controller      xhci     Version 1.0, Build: 4600944, Interfac...
Sky Lake-E PCI Express Root Port 1D       PCI bridge          vmkernel Version Releasebuild-5050593
VIC 1300 PCIe Upstream Port               PCI bridge          vmkernel Version Releasebuild-5050593
VIC PCIe Downstream Port                  PCI bridge          vmkernel Version Releasebuild-5050593
VIC PCIe Upstream Port                    PCI bridge          vmkernel Version Releasebuild-5050593
x1 PCIe Gen2 Bridge[Pilot4]               PCI bridge          vmkernel Version Releasebuild-5050593
```